# Extracting table from Confusion Matrix

Tags: r, confusion-matrix

I have the following confusion matrix (received from summary of model `summary (model)` ):

```
=== Confusion Matrix ===

   a   b   c   <-- classified as
 344  12   4 |   a = 1
  28  43   4 |   b = 2
   9   1  32 |   c = 3
```

I would like to extract into df1 just the matrix content as followed:

```
  a   b   c 
 344  12   4
  28  43   4
   9   1  32
```

We should take into consideration that the size of the matrix can be changed. I need a general solution.
Is there a way to extract it straightforward from the model and from txt file as well?

Comment: Are you trying to reverse the table() function?

Comment: Or perhaps `class(yourconfusionmatrix) <- 'matrix';names(dimnames(yourconfusionmatrix)) <- NULL`

Comment: I have it just in txt format. The source of it is the summary of the model. I would like to use the content of the content of the confusion matrix for post analysis.

Comment: @Avi Try changing the `class` to `matrix` and assign the names of dimnames  to NULL.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My source model is from J48 model:

```
> class(summary (model) ) 
[1] "Weka_classifier_evaluation"
```

In order to get the confusion matrix:

```
> summary (model)$confusionMatrix
   predicted
      1  2  3
  1 344  12   4
  2  28  43   4
  3   9   1  32
```

Comment: @akrun, This is the matrix I needed. It is the answer. Here is the dput (summary (model)$confusionMatrix) 
structure(c(357, 12, 3, 20, 37, 1, 7, 11, 29), .Dim = c(3L, 3L
), .Dimnames = structure(list(c("1", "2", "3"), predicted = c("1", 
"2", "3")), .Names = c("", "predicted")))

Comment: In that case, you answered it.